# using localization in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, localization

How can I localize strings in cakePhp? I havent had any success with the online documentation. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `"havent had any success with the online documentation"`? As in "I couldn't find the right section in my cursory sweep" or as in "I tried a few things which I won't bother telling you about but they didn't work"? Either way, bad question. L10n is well documented in the Cake manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of steps:

1. First, set the locale to be used
2. Create one or more `.po` files for that language
3. Wrap all of your l10n-able strings with the `__()` or `__d()` helper methods

Here's an excerpt from one of my projects:

```
# app/app_controller.php
uses ( 'L10n' );

class AppController extends Controller {
  public function beforeFilter() {
    /**
     * Derive the desired locale by reading the subdomain from
     * the HTTP_HOST server variable. Locale subdomains can use
     * either the 2 or 3 character ISO code. Information on locale
     * ISO codes is at http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php.
     */
    $this->L10n = new L10n();

    /** Auto-detect the request language settings */
    $this->L10n->get();

    /**
     * Set the default "domain" for translations. The domain is the
     * same as the po file name in a given locale directory. e.g.
     * __d( 'homepage', 'message_id' ) would look for the
     * message_id key in homepage.po. Using the __() convenience
     * function will always look in default.po.
     */
    $this->set( 'domain', 'default' );
  }

  # The rest of your AppController code
}
```

That snippet will set the language. All you need to do is provide the appropriate `.po` files in the `/app/locale/eng/LC_MESSAGES/` directory. The CakePHP book provides [sufficient information on this](http://book.cakephp.org/view/161/Internationalization-Localization), I think.

If you choose to use just one `.po` file, you'll wrap your strings with the `__()` helper. I chose multiple `.po` files in order to avoid one massive file, so I used the `__d()` helper so that I could specify which domain (domain == name of the `.po` file without the `.po` extension).

**UPDATE**

I should add that you'll need to use the `Translate` behavior to help you with database content that requires translation.

Comment: You do not need to instantiate the `L10n` class at all. This happens automatically the first time the `__()` function is invoked.

Comment: Interesting. I did not know that, but since I'm using it here to `get()` the language, wouldn't I need an instance before any `__()` is evaluated?

Comment: No, this is all being done when you invoke `__()`. You can try by baking a new Cake app and just add a single `__('Test')` somewhere, provide a translation .po file for the string and switch your browsers preferred language setting. It'll switch languages without you needing to do anything more.

Comment: There is no way how to change default "domain", __() always uses default domain.

Answer (score 0):

**CakePHP 3.x  Localization**

Create the action for dynamic language change

Route

```
$routes->connect('/locale', ['controller' => ' Users', 'action' => 'languageChange']);
```

**Controller Action**

**UsersController**

```
use Cake\Http\Session;
use Cake\I18n\I18n;

//Before filter in users controller
public function beforeFilter(\Cake\Event\Event $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
    }


      /**
     * Change language
     */
    public function languageChange()
    {
               if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
            if (!empty($this->request->getData('locale'))) {
                $session->write('Config.language', $this->request->getData('locale'));
                $this->redirect($this->referer());
            } else {
                $session->write('Config.language', I18n::getLocale());
                $this->redirect($this->referer());
            }
        }
    }
```

Create view file mean language_change.ctp file

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create("Localizations", array('url' => '/locale'));
echo $this->Form->radio("locale", [
    ['value' => 'en_US', 'text' => 'English'],
    ['value' => 'de_DE', 'text' => 'German'],
    ['value' => 'fr_FR', 'text' => 'French'],
]);
echo $this->Form->button('Change Language');
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
<h2><?php echo __('Hello'); ?></h2>
<h2><?php echo __('How are you?'); ?></h2>
<h2><?php echo __('Wel Come'); ?></h2>
<h2><?php echo __('Good Job'); ?></h2>
```

- This execute flow is
- First call action language change ex- http://example.local/locale
- Then change language select radio button  change language

**AppController**

```
use Cake\I18n\I18n;
use Cake\Http\Session;
use Cake\Core\Configure;


 public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();

        if ($session->check('Config.language')) {
            I18n::setLocale($session->read('Config.language'));
        } else {
            $session->write('Config.language', I18n::getLocale());
        }
    }
```

Create this location in files
src/Locale/en_US/default.po

```
msgid "Hello"
msgstr "Hello"

msgid "How are you?"
msgstr "How are you?"

msgid "Wel Come"
msgstr "Wel Come"

msgid "Good Job"
msgstr "Good Job"
```

- src/Locale/de_DE/default.po

  ```
  msgid "Hello"
  msgstr "Hallo"

  msgid "How are you?"
  msgstr "Hoe gaat het met je?"

  msgid "Wel Come"
  msgstr "Wel kom"

  msgid "Good Job"
  msgstr "Goed gedaan"
  ```
- Configure in boostrap.php

  'Session' => [
              'defaults' => 'php',
              'language' => 'en_US'
          ]