# Internationalization and Localization in CakePHP 2.1

Tags: cakephp, localization, internationalization

I am building a dual language app in CakePHP 2.1.x because of the great reviews of Cake's "built-in" localization features. However, I am wrestling with getting this powerful feature to work.

I know that this topic has been tackled for previous versions of Cake ([here](http://www.cakephparticles.com/cakephp-internationalization-and-localization), [here](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/11/28/cakephp-url-based-language-switching-for-i18n-and-l10n-internationalization-and-localization),  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661275/using-localization-in-cakephp), and [here](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/p0windah/2007/09/12/p28n-the-top-to-bottom-persistent-internationalization-tutorial)), but it hasn't been solved for Cake 2.x. I am also referencing these articles in the cookbook (yes, I've read the manual):

- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html
- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/translate.html

Couple of things -- I do not want to do separate subdomains for each language. Instead, I prefer URL based language switching with the click of a button (in this case, a flag icon). The site will be actively maintained, so the content needs to update dynamically. Asking the client to maintain two separate sites/databases is out of the question.

I have Translate behavior set up for my PostModel, but I can't tell if it's working. I also initialized I18n by running `I18n` in the console, have confirmed the database tables exist, have set up my .po files, and have wrapped all my content in `__()`. However, when I change the default language in my browser to French, the site remains in English.

I've tried the P28n Component, but I think it's outdated for Cake 2.x. I also tried URL-based language switching based on this [nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp article](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/11/28/cakephp-url-based-language-switching-for-i18n-and-l10n-internationalization-and-localization), but apparently it's incompatible with the new CakePHP API.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a tutorial or instructions that work with CakePHP 2.x? One not already referenced here?

**Update:** I found this article: http://www.localizingjapan.com/blog/2011/11/10/localizing-a-cakephp-application/comment-page-1/#comment-7467. Does anyone know where you place the code for `CakeSession::write('Config.language', 'fre');` and `setlocale("LC_ALL", "fr_FR.utf8");`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put the code in AppController::beforeFilter() and set the values based on however you retrieve the language, from a post request or a part of the URL.

Comment: Thanks, burzum! Here is my `beforeFilter()` in AppController:

`public function beforeFilter() {
 parent::beforeFilter();
     CakeSession::write('Config.language', 'fre');
     setlocale("LC_ALL", "fr_FR.utf8");
 $this->Auth->allow('index','view','home','display','logout');
}`

Comment: So far, that doesn't seem to have any effect on the site. Here is the URL: puzzle.leadingedgecommunications.net. Also, I want the locale to change on a button click. How do I do that?

Comment: The problem was with my .po files. I also ended up not needing setlocale() at all.